# Is there a product that allows me to run a "mains" device off a power tool Battery

Tags: powertools, battery

I have some fairly large DeWalt 18V batteries, which run, e.g. my Cordless LawnMower.

I imagine that they'd also run my Corded tools, at least for a while, if I could connect them up.

But I can't find any such DeWalt product :( And I don't know what term to search.
All I find when I do searches is products designed to allow the opposite - running a battery tool from the mains.

Do these products exist? and if so what keywords should I be searching for?

Comment: Inverter is the word you can search for.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure product recommendations are on-topic here, but DeWalt does make a **20V Flexvolt series** product called the [Portable Power Station](https://www.dewalt.com/products/storage-and-gear/generators-and-portable-power/1800-watt-portable-power-station-and-simultaneous-battery-charger/dcb1800b) DCB1800 which can supply 120VAC @ 15A.  It also functions as a charger for your batteries.  It's not cheap, though.